# Требуется помощь в написании запроса UPDATE REPLACE

Tags: mysql, sql, update, replace

Возникла необходимость внести массовое изменение в карточках товаров Woocommerce двух символов. Проблема заключается в том, что сайт двуязычный (руский/украинский) и замена требуется только для одного языка. Слова, которые треубют замены букв находятся в таблице.

Выглядит это примерно так:

```
<td rowspan="2" width="95">Число обертів втулки откр./закр.</td> <td colspan="2" width="246">Электропривод</td></tr><tr> <td width="47">ЦКБА</td> <td width="47">ISO</td> <td style="text-align: center;" width="132">электропривод</td>
```

Нужно, чтобы выглядело:

```
<td rowspan="2" width="95">Число обертів втулки откр./закр.</td> <td colspan="2" width="246">Електропривод</td></tr><tr> <td width="47">ЦКБА</td> <td width="47">ISO</td> <td style="text-align: center;" width="132">електропривод</td>
```

Пробовал выполнить следующий запрос:

```
update adm_postmeta set meta_value = replace(meta_value, '<td rowspan='"2"' width='"95"'>Число обертів втулки откр.'/'закр.</td>\r\n<td colspan='"2"' width='"246"'>Электропривод</td></tr><tr>\r\n<td width='"47"'>ЦКБА</td>\r\n<td width='"47"'>ISO</td>\r\n<td style='"text-align: center"' width='"132"'>Тула -электропривод</td>','<td rowspan='"2"' width='"95"'>Число обертів втулки откр.'/'закр.</td>\r\n<td colspan='"2"' width='"246"'>Електропривод</td></tr><tr>\r\n<td width='"47"'>ЦКБА</td>\r\n<td width='"47"'>ISO</td>\r\n<td style='"text-align: center"' width='"132"'>Тула -електропривод</td>')
```

В результате получаю Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value...
Какие есть варианты решения?

Comment: а обычный replace не работает? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e2aa6f8a274de11dd7bea791eef3e284

Comment: MySql 5.7, такой запрос вряд ли подхватит

Comment: Укажите используемую СУБД, добавьте метку.

Comment: @alexander-petrov указал

Comment: @encore в 5.6 все работает https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=406a1c8410cb78458254f6bfff14e87d

Comment: @novitskiy-denis К сожалению нет, поэтому и спросил здесь.Мне все время выдает `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''<td rowspan="2" width="95">Число обертів втулки откр./з' at line 1`

Comment: @encore вы выполнили мой запрос у себя? какая ошибка?

Comment: да, ошибка #1064.

Comment: @encore сделайте скрин ошибки и запроса

Comment: @novitskiy-denis (http://joxi.ru/RmzJGRBiRkQeVm)

Comment: @с вашими названиями таблиц и вашей версией MySQL - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qUWLEpjzo148ZzDiNoY3hQ/0

Comment: @novitskiy-denis необходимые для замены данные находятся в таблице adm_postmeta и SET выбрано meta_value. При запросе по ссылке пустой результат.

Comment: @encore так у вас на скрине таблица adm_posts и столбец post_content. пожалуйста, определитесь. чтобы увидеть результат запроса - нажмите Run

Comment: @novitskiy-denis (http://joxi.ru/52aP6GXTb5NGqm) вот так правильнее. В любом случае, оба результат приводят к "Затронуто 0 строк". Видимо Mysql не понимает наличие пробелов в строках. Пробовал добавить \r\n и двойные кавычки - результат или ошибка или 0 строк.

Comment: @encore все отлично понимает и выполняет - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qUWLEpjzo148ZzDiNoY3hQ/1

Comment: @novitskiy-denis так-то все в порядке на модуляторе, но реальная база Wordpress выкидывает нулевой резльтат.

Comment: @novitskiy-denis может быть добавить WHERE? Данные в колонке "yikes_woo_products_tabs". Поможете составить правильный запрос?

Comment: выполните этот запрос ```select meta_value from adm_postmeta where meta_value='<td rowspan="2" width="95">Число обертів втулки откр./закр.</td> <td colspan="2" width="246">Электропривод</td></tr><tr> <td width="47">ЦКБА</td> <td width="47">ISO</td> <td style="text-align: center;" width="132">электропривод</td>'```. В выборку попали какие-то строки?

Comment: @novitskiy-denis MySQL вернула пустой результат (т.е. ноль строк).

Comment: @encore ну так у вас в базе нет такой записи. что вы хотите изменить?

Comment: @novitskiy-denis Выполнил поиск по слову из проблемного участка в базе: SELECT * FROM `adm`.`adm_postmeta` WHERE (CONVERT(`meta_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%обертів%' OR CONVERT(`post_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%обертів%' OR CONVERT(`meta_key` USING utf8) LIKE '%обертів%' OR CONVERT(`meta_value` USING utf8) LIKE '%обертів%')

Comment: @encore в каком столбце пробемное значение - его и обновляйте.

Comment: Может, проще будет использовать [XML Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html)? Хоть это html, но вполне может парситься как xml.

Comment: @alexander-petrov, можно подробней?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov для начала автору бы определиться, какой столбец обновлять:)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov столбец в базе известен, но содержит он почти 89к строк. Полагаю проблема найти строку, а не столбец))